# Create a registry key/string with Go

Tags: go, registry

I was following this [document](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry) to create a key/string in windows registry with this code snippet:

```golang
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.CURRENT_USER, `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Audio`, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    k.SetStringValue("xyz", "blahblah")
    err = k.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

but nothing happens, without any errors.
Edit (clarification): It doesn't work, in any circumstances.

Comment: what did you expect to happen? change the key value? "nothing happens" is a bit too broad don't you think?

Comment: You are ignoring the errors from SetStringvalue and from Close. What output do you expect if you deliberately close your eyes? Handle all errors, always.

Comment: **NOTHING HAPPENS** means it doesn't work, that, it doesn't create or set any registry values. apologies for ambiguation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are opening the key with only the `QUERY_VALUE` permission, but you also need `SET_VALUE` in order to successfully call `SetStringValue`.

You should also be checking the return value on `SetStringValue`, which would have likely informed you what the problem was.

```
k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.CURRENT_USER, `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Audio`, registry.QUERY_VALUE|registry.SET_VALUE)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := k.SetStringValue("xyz", "blahblah"); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := k.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```