# Creating Registry Key with Golang

Tags: windows, go, registry, exe

I am currently trying to add a Windows registry key using Golang instead of using the following Powershell query: `Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath “C:\Temp”`. The registry key is meant to be added to Windows Defender Exclusions but I am getting one of two errors, either; `The system cannot find the file specified.The handle is invalid` or `Access is Denied`.

I've currently tried two different methods, both without success. The registry key location is `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths`. In order to access the registry, the following library was imported:

`import "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"`

The following query does run and it returns the expected information:

```
winInfo, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
check(err)
defer winInfo.Close()

CurrentVersion, _, err := winInfo.GetStringValue("CurrentVersion")
check(err)

fmt.Printf("Value: " + CurrentVersion)
```

However, when attempting to add in a registry key to the Windows Defender exclusions, the following code returns the error: `The system cannot find the file specified.The handle is invalid`

```
regInfo, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths`, registry.ALL_ACCESS)
check(err)
defer winInfo.Close()

err = regInfo.SetDWordValue("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\file.exe",0)
check(err)
```

The answer in the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542609/create-a-registry-key-string-with-go) link here also returned the above error. In order to try find a different workaround, I have tried the following, which returns the error: `Access is Denied`.

```
import "github.com/gen0cide/gscript/x/windows"

windows.AddRegKeyString("LOCAL_MACHINE", "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Exclusions\\Paths", "file.exe", "C:\\Windows\\Temp");
```

I have tried running both queries using a low privileged account as well as from an elevated CMD window, i.e. `Run as Administrator`.

Any advice on how I would be able to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Following on from this, I went down a rabbit hole with trying to figure out what was wrong and whether I had the required permissions to access this registry key. I viewed the ACLs for the registry, used procmon to figure out if something was wrong, used REG QUERY as low priv, etc. All of which pointed to the fact that I should be able to at least read from this registry key.

I then decided to try implement it in Python to see if it was something to do with 3rd party software not being able to access the Registry. The following code was used, and it did return the required information:

```
import errno, os, winreg

RawKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion",0, winreg.KEY_READ)
print(winreg.QueryValueEx(RawKey,"CurrentVersion"))


RawKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender",0, winreg.KEY_READ)
print(winreg.QueryValueEx(RawKey,"BackupLocation"))
```

I have now raised an issue with the Golang team to figure out if this is an issue with the Golang registry implementation or if it's an issue of my implementation of the registry calls.

Answer (score 0):

In an Admin run terminal the following worked for me.

```
import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
        "path"

        "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)   

    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\YourPath`, registry.WRITE)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
            return err
        }
        defer k.Close()

        if err = k.SetStringValue(key, val); err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
            return
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In Windows, the `Administrator` account does not necessarily [have access to everything on the system](https://superuser.com/questions/504136/root-vs-administrator-vs-system/504405). An example is this registry key.

There is a [Powershell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/add-mppreference) that does allow you to add an exclusion:

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Windows\Temp\file.exe"
```

To call this from Go, you can execute the script with `exec.Command`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    _,err := exec.Command("powershell.exe", `Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Windows\Temp\file.exe"`).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("success")
}
```

Make sure you run this script as an Administrator. If you want the executable to request elevated permissions when running, see [this repository](https://github.com/mozey/run-as-admin).

Comment: I have tried and used the powershell script before, which is why I mentioned it. I'm looking for a way to do it in golang without having to use powershell if possible

Comment: My bad. Apparently I skipped over that part. Don't expect it is possible without the script. I will take a look at getting the script to work from Golang later today.

Comment: No worries, I just find it strange that I can modify some registry keys and not the one for windows defender

Comment: That's by design. By letting you go through that script, Windows can put some checks in place before allowing a change to the exclude list. If they let you edit the registry key directly, malware can just add itself to the exclusion list. What I can imagine the script does, is check first whether there is any known malware running, if so, deny the request.

Comment: I've added a code sample that works for me on Windows when running as Administrator.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that is just the same powershell command wrapped in go? Maybe there's some ambiguity in the way I'm asking the question, but I'm looking for a way to do it without powershell